# CSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Tags: disk-usage

Super ignorant in Linux here.  I have built a Linux/Ubuntu server as a syslog server to collect logs from all my routers.  I don't log in much but logged in today and was hit by the "No space left on device" message.  I did a 'df -lh' command and found that the /dev/sda1 director is 100% used:

[image]

I think this has caused the server to stopped collecting the logs.  What can I do to fix this.  If you have any instruction for me, please give me step by step.

Thank you
Kit

Comment: clean up some files to create space.  `/var/log` is probably the easiest dir but if this is a logging server... you will remove logs defeating the purpose of the server ;)

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; is this a Ubuntu Core server? or Ubuntu Server?   I'd suggest allocating more space if you don't want to maintain it more regularly as it'll likely happen again unless you explore what has filled it, how you can manage it (*we need details as to what it is in order to help guide you*) on your *unstated* server system.   I'd use `du` (*disk-usage you tagged*) to find where the space is used... and start from there.  As you only allocated 29GB you've not given it much space either (*unless there is more than you provided*)

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments.  I've started a ticket with Microsoft.  I will update here when i have new news.  Thanks.